# How can I share login between subprojects?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication

I'm implementing an application in ASP.NET MVC 4 with subprojects and I want these aplications to share same login (just login in one application and no need to login into the subprojects).

With webForms, we usually use the machine key to do it, but in MVC 4 it doesn't work anymore. **There's any new solution to this in  MVC 4?**

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13340692/674700).

Answer (score 0):

Since the **`Forms authentication`** is done through a Forms authentication `ticket`, if all applications share one authentication ticket, a user will only be required to log in once, thus, single sign-on. Let’s say we have two applications with these URLs:

```
http://public.mysite.com/app1/default1.aspx
http://public.mysite.com/app2/default2.aspx
```

As you can see, they are basically two virtual directories under the same sub domain - `public.mysite.com.` A cookie written by **app1** will be visible by **app2**, and vice versa.

However, this does not mean when a user logs into **app1**, he is automatically logged into **app2**. The reason is that each ASP.NET application, by default, uses its own encryption keys to create a Forms authentication ticket and cookie. Therefore, the cookie written by app1 can’t be successfully read by **app2**, even though it is visible to **app2**.

> How can we make the two applications recognize each other’s
>   authentication ticket and cookie?

In fact, it is pretty simple in ASP.NET. The only thing that needs to be done is to change the settings in the  element of the web.config file. Here are the default settings for machinKey:

```
<machineKey 
validationKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps" 
decryptionKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps" 
validation="SHA1" 
decryption="Auto" 
/>
```

With these settings, the .NET framework uses the automatically generated `validationKey` and `decrytionKey` to create an authentication ticket and cookie. Each application uses different keys. To make multiple applications to share the same authentication ticket and cookie, we just need to set the `validationKey` and `decrytionKey` in all the applications to the same values.

To generate the keys, the `RNGCryptoSErviceProvider` class in the `System.Security.Cryptography` namespace is utilized, as shown in the following code sample:

```
 public String CreateKey(int numBytes)
 {
 RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
 byte[] buff = new byte[numBytes];
 rng.GetBytes(buff);
 return BytesToHexString(buff);
 }

 private String BytesToHexString(byte[] bytes)
 {
 StringBuilder hexString = new StringBuilder(64);
 for (int counter = 0; counter < bytes.Length; counter++)
 {
     hexString.Append(String.Format("{0:X2}", bytes[counter]));
 }
 return hexString.ToString();
 }
```