# Auto Login user from another website?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-membership, asp.net-3.5

I have an MVC app that has a link that calls an action method of another MVC app that should automatically login the user.  I have all the user information via:

```
var user = Membership.GetUser(userName);
```

But from here, I have no idea how to auto login the user.

The two websites are on different domains and my password is hashed.

Comment: This link below should be helpful .

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339091/method-for-sharing-forms-authentication-login-between-mvc-net-and-web-api-sites

Comment: @Sid - I am on different domains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you just call [SetAuthCookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.setauthcookie.aspx) to let the user login to the site, since you already know the username.

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, false);
```

Comment: Will this work if the sites are on different domains, for example, the site with the link will be `www.abc.com` and it will call an action method from `www.def.com` and this action method will look the user up and sign them in.  Also, what does false do in the method?

Comment: It should work as far as I know. [true to create a persistent cookie; otherwise, false.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twk5762b.aspx)

Comment: Win, I saw it meant persistent, but not sure exactly what it means when it says it saves it across sessions?

Comment: It is used for ***Remember Me/[Keep me signed in](https://login.live.com/)*** checkbox which you seen in some websites. If you set to true, user doesn't need to ***re-enter*** username and password for a certain amount of time. In your case, it might not be needed.

Comment: I setup a test were I had a link with a good login and it worked and I also had a link with a bad login, it worked but what it does it it redirects me to a page saying I am unauthorized, but it still shows me loggd in as the other user.